# Distribute ratings data to increase the standard deviation

Tags: php, mysql, statistics, rating, rating-system

Given a table of items, each with a rating between 0 and 100. What is the term or approach I need to research in order to distribute the values more 'evenly' relative to each other? I realise I am looking to increase the standard deviation value.

I believe this must be quite a common problem with rating systems. Where ~90% of the items in the database converge around similar 'ratings' making the value is less meaningful. Ideally I'd like a solution where a given item's rating is in some way relative to all the others in the table.

Ultimately I'm looking to achieve this either directly in SQL (MySQL) or if necessary PHP.

An example below...

```
id  |  rating

01  |  98 
02  |  92 
03  |  85 
04  |  80 
05  |  75 
06  |  71 
07  |  69 
08  |  66 
09  |  64
10  |  62     //Data starts to 'cluster' around here
11  |  61 
12  |  61 
13  |  61 
14  |  60 
15  |  59
16  |  58
17  |  56
18  |  53
19  |  50
20  |  45
21  |  38
22  |  30
23  |  20
24  |  5
```

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve?  What does the output result look like?  Why are you trying to "doctor" ratings values?

Comment: The problem is the nature of the existing rating system is causing approximately 80% of items in the table to converge to a rating of around 50-60% making it difficult to portray a sense of 'range' to the results.

As an end user, it'd be good to see an items rating, relative to every other item.

Comment: The output would be more 'spread out' results - so if plotted on a graph of number of items vs. rating, it'd be a 'flatter' gaussian curve.

Comment: . . I typical approach is to put values into quantiles, often deciles, for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in MySQL, but it requires a few calculations. First, you need the mean average and standard deviation. Both are MySQL functions. Then, how many standard deviations from the mean do consider a valid value? I will assume it is 2 because that is common. Now, Mean-(2*StdDev) is the minimum value and Mean+(2*StdDev) is the max value. Assume you wrote a query (please note that I am using Oracle 100% of the time these days, so I may get the syntax a bit Oracle-like):

```
select avg(value)-2*stddev(value) minval,
avg(value)+2*stddev(value) maxval
from mytable
```

You can make that a subquery and join on it. Then, you can calculate the percentage between min and max val:

```
select (value-mival)/(maxval-minval) pctval
from mytable
join (
    select avg(value)-2*stddev(value) minval,
    avg(value)+2*stddev(value) maxval
    from mytable
)
```

The result will be a percent from minval to maxval. You can multiply that by 100 to get values 0 to 100 (there will be values <0 and >100 for outliers).

Answer (score 0):

here's using just php

```
<?php
$cart = array();
$cart[] = 98;
$cart[] = 92;
$cart[] = 85;
$cart[] = 80;
$cart[] = 75;
$cart[] = 71;
$cart[] = 69;
$cart[] = 66;
$cart[] = 64;
$cart[] = 62;
$cart[] = 61;
$cart[] = 61;
$cart[] = 61;
$cart[] = 60;
$cart[] = 59;
$cart[] = 58;
$cart[] = 56;
$cart[] = 53;
$cart[] = 50;
$cart[] = 45;
$cart[] = 38;
$cart[] = 30;
$cart[] = 20;
$cart[] = 5;
echo stats_standard_deviation($cart);
function stats_standard_deviation(array $a, $sample = false) {
    $n = count($a);
    if ($n === 0) {
        trigger_error("The array has zero elements", E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    if ($sample && $n === 1) {
        trigger_error("The array has only 1 element", E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    $mean = array_sum($a) / $n;
    $carry = 0.0;
    foreach ($a as $val) {
        $d = ((double) $val) - $mean;
        $carry += $d * $d;
    };
    if ($sample) {
       --$n;
    }
    return sqrt($carry / $n);
}
?>
```

the standard deviation is 20.7812265037,

this means any rating number within + or - 20 of 62 is normal (68% of rating numbers are normal)